# Unable to solve validation error in flask

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I am a newbie into flask development.I am facing a peculiar validation error in Flask . My main code is as follows :

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,redirect,url_for,session,request
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired
from wtforms import TextAreaField,SelectField,StringField

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'MySecret!'

def get_choices():
    names = [
               (1,"George"),
               (2,"Musk"),
               (3,"Stevens")
            ]
    return names

@app.route('/',methods=["GET","POST"])
def index():
    class TestForm(FlaskForm):
        name = StringField("Name",validators=[InputRequired()])
        lastname = SelectField("Lastname",choices=get_choices())

    t = TestForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        if t.validate_on_submit():
            name = t.name.data
            lastname = t.lastname.data
            return "<h1> {} and {} </h1>".format(name,lastname)
        else:
            return "Validation Failed !!"

    return render_template('index.html',form=t)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The code for my index.html is as follows :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        {{ form.name.label }}
        {{ form.name }}
        {{ form.lastname.label }}
        {{ form.lastname }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Every time i submit the form i get the form not validated message . I am not sure where i am going wrong. I have to deliberately keep the class definition inside the route function so that i can emulate a run time situation in which i am not sure of the from contents until runtime.

Please guide me where the issue is, also can someone give me some hint on is there a way to debug validation errors like the above in Flask ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to add `coerce=int` in your `SelectField` as in:

`SelectField("Lastname", coerce=int , choices=get_choices())`

Answer (score 0):

As per @davidism suggestion, I debugged using `t.errors`. 
I found that the problem occurred due to mapping the choices to integer in the `SelectField`.

There are two ways of get rid of this error:

1. Add `coerce=int` in the `lastname` of the form to get dynamic choice
   values (e.g.: 1, 2, 3 etc.).
2. Pass string as first parameter of the
   `names` list.

**Solution 1:**

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,redirect,url_for,session,request
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired
from wtforms import TextAreaField,SelectField,StringField

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'MySecret!'

def get_choices():
    names = [
               (1,"George"),
               (2,"Musk"),
               (3,"Stevens")
            ]
    return names

@app.route('/',methods=["GET","POST"])
def index():
    class TestForm(FlaskForm):
        name = StringField("Name",validators=[InputRequired()])
        lastname = SelectField("Lastname",choices=get_choices(), coerce=int)

    t = TestForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        if t.validate_on_submit():
            name = t.name.data
            lastname = t.lastname.data
            return "<h1> {} and {} </h1>".format(name,lastname)
        else:
            print t.errors
            return "Validation Failed !!"

    return render_template('index.html',form=t)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

After submitting the form I got:

[image: output]

Getting `1` as last name might not your expected value. 
You may use string value as first parameter of the choices; in this case `names` list.

**Solution 2:**

So, if we remove the `coerce` property and update our choice list like:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,redirect,url_for,session,request
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired
from wtforms import TextAreaField,SelectField,StringField

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'MySecret!'

def get_choices():
    names = [
               ("George","George"),
               ("Musk","Musk"),
               ("Stevens","Stevens")
            ]
    return names

@app.route('/',methods=["GET","POST"])
def index():
    class TestForm(FlaskForm):
        name = StringField("Name",validators=[InputRequired()])
        lastname = SelectField("Lastname",choices=get_choices())

    t = TestForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        if t.validate_on_submit():
            name = t.name.data
            lastname = t.lastname.data
            return "<h1> {} and {} </h1>".format(name,lastname)
        else:
            print t.errors
            return "Validation Failed !!"

    return render_template('index.html',form=t)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This time, we get:

[image: output of solution 2]

Now it makes sense as a last name.

**References:**

- Examples of selectField [in wtforms official documentation](http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html).